# A simple methodology to merge Array of the nested object into an array of the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm looking for a simple methodology to merge the Array of the nested object into an array of the same object

**Input:**

```
const data=[
      { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 , address:{city:"chennai", zipcode:600001}},
      { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23, address:{city:"cbe", zipcode:600002} },
      { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23, address:{city:"tiruppur", zipcode:600003}},
      { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23, address:{city:"erode", zipcode:600004} },
      { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23, address:{city:"selam", zipcode:600005} }
    ]
```

**Needed Output:**

```
      { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23, city:"chennai", zipcode:600001},
      { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23, city:"cbe", zipcode:600002},
      { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23, city:"tiruppur", zipcode:600003},
      { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23, city:"erode", zipcode:600004},
      { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23, city:"selam", zipcode:600005}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of destructuring and spread syntax:

```js
const data=[{ id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 , address:{city:"chennai", zipcode:600001}},{ id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23, address:{city:"cbe", zipcode:600002} },{ id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23, address:{city:"tiruppur", zipcode:600003}},{ id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23, address:{city:"erode", zipcode:600004} },{ id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23, address:{city:"selam", zipcode:600005} }];

const result = data.map(({address, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...address}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to extract each property and its value in the `address` property and assign it to the parent object, then delete the `address` property.

```js
const data=[{id:123,name:"dave",age:23,address:{city:"chennai",zipcode:600001}},{id:456,name:"chris",age:23,address:{city:"cbe",zipcode:600002}},{id:789,name:"bob",age:23,address:{city:"tiruppur",zipcode:600003}},{id:101,name:"tom",age:23,address:{city:"erode",zipcode:600004}},{id:102,name:"tim",age:23,address:{city:"selam",zipcode:600005}}];

const result = data.map(e => (Object.entries(e.address).forEach(f => e[f[0]] = f[1]), delete e.address, e))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `.map` here, when the original array is already mutated?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
    { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23, address: { city: "chennai", zipcode: 600001 } },
    { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23, address: { city: "cbe", zipcode: 600002 } },
    { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23, address: { city: "tiruppur", zipcode: 600003 } },
    { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23, address: { city: "erode", zipcode: 600004 } },
    { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23, address: { city: "selam", zipcode: 600005 } }
]

data = data.map((node) => ({ id: node.id, name: node.name, age: node.age, city: node.address.city, zipcode: node.address.zipcode }))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data=[
      { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 , address:{city:"chennai", zipcode:600001}},
      { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23, address:{city:"cbe", zipcode:600002} },
      { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23, address:{city:"tiruppur", zipcode:600003}},
      { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23, address:{city:"erode", zipcode:600004} },
      { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23, address:{city:"selam", zipcode:600005} }
    ];
    
const result = data.map(item => ({id: item.id, name: item.name, age: item.age, ...item.address}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: please avoid code only answers. A description helps all users understand the reasoning behind your answer